# Capacitor GeoLocation Permissions on Ionic PWA

Tags: ios, permissions, geolocation, capacitor

I'm building an Ionic PWA that uses the Capacitor Geolocation plugin and I want to make sure the user has given proper permission so I'm using the Permissions plugin: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/permissions

It seems to be working fine in Android, but I'm getting the following error on iOS/Safari when it tries to call the permissions query:
"This browser does not support the Permissions API"

Is there something else I need to do so it works on iOS?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Did you add Locations permissions in Info.plist file?

Comment: As I stated, it's a PWA, so I'm not aware it has an Info.plist file.